# app that reminds to take a break at times

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, applications

I am looking out for an app (for Mac OS X) that reminds to take a break (gives out a message) at pre-scheduled time.

Free (or low cost) app will do, as I don't want to spend my hard earned cash on this simple app.

Comment: The pomodoro technique is very similar. You might find this list useful: http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/717/which-computer-based-pomodoro-timers-exist-and-what-are-their-features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application that I use to be aware of the time on the computer is [awareness](http://iamfutureproof.com/tools/awareness/) it don't put a message only a sound indicating the time you have been using the computer without a break.

Comment: I am using Awareness, and found it useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is one such tool I know, called (unsurprisingly) [Time Out](http://dejal.net/timeout/). It's free as in beer and seems to be well-maintained.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to limit the time you spend online, you can use the freely available app [Freedom](http://macfreedom.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[AntiRSI](http://tech.inhelsinki.nl/antirsi/) does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a quick google search and this question came up. You can also try [Rest](http://rest.dangelov.com), which is a break reminder app that can also suggest exercise suggestions.

Disclaimer: I made it.